# File.WriteAllBytes is creating a 0 byte file

Tags: c#, file, unity-game-engine, byte

I'm currently working on a puzzle game, and trying to make an auto update program. So the user can update their game without manually downloading the latest version. The version checking itself is working, however when I'm trying to download the file using WWW(url) it takes quite some time to download, but once I check in my file browser it has created a 0 byte file. And in OSX it actually gets removed instantly.

This is the code that I'm using.

```
void UpdateGame(){
    string path = Application.dataPath;
    if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.OSXPlayer) {
        path += "/../../";
    }
    else if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.WindowsPlayer) {
        path += "/../";
    }

    if (System.IO.File.Exists (path+"/Apo_Alpha.app")) {
        Debug.Log ("File exists!");
        System.IO.File.Delete (path+"/Apo_Alpha.app");

    }


        WWW www = new WWW ("https://www.dropbox.com/sh/aayo9iud7t98hgb/AACDqSST_-rT2jIfxq1Zc2SXa?dl=1");

    while (!www.isDone) {
        Debug.Log ("Waiting for download");
    }

        string fullPath = path+"/Apo_Alpha.app";
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes (fullPath, www.bytes);

    Debug.Log ("Done downloading...");
    Debug.Log ("File downloaded at " + fullPath);

}
```

Why is this happening? Is it because I maybe have to wait for those bytes to have been written? I'd love to get some form of help here. I'm sure it's just a small error, but I can't find the answer anywhere. (the URL's are correct, I double checked them...)

Comment: I don't know Unity well, but the `isDone` documentation explicitly says "You should not write loops that spin until download is done; use coroutines instead."

Comment: Just a note (not related to your problem): Checking for `File.Exist` does not make sure it is still existing once the next line is executing, or that you have proper permissions to delete it. You still need to catch exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when I'm trying to download the file using WWW(url) it takes quite
>   some time to download

That's because you are blocking the main Thread. This should be done in a coroutine.

```
IEnumerator downLoadFromServer()
{
    WWW www = new WWW("yourUrl");
    yield return www;
    Debug.Log("Done downloading");

    byte[] yourBytes = www.bytes;

    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(fullPath, yourBytes);
}
```

Then call/start the coroutine with `StartCoroutine(downLoadFromServer());`

Now, if you want to use `www.isDone`, you must yield in the coroutine function or Unity main Thread will freeze till the file is downloaded.

Here is an example of how `www.isDone` should be used:

```
IEnumerator downLoadFromServer()
{
    string url = "https://www.dropbox.com/sh/aayo9iud7t98hgb/AACDqSST_-rT2jIfxq1Zc2SXa?dl=1";

    WWW www = new WWW(url);

    while (!www.isDone)
    {
        //Must yield below/wait for a frame
        yield return null;
    }

    Debug.Log("Done downloading");

    byte[] yourBytes = www.bytes;

    //Now Save it
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(fullPath, yourBytes);
}
```

Finally, don't create the path by hand. Don't do stuff like this:

`path += "/../";`

Use `Path.Combine` to do that:

```
path = Path.Combine(path,"Other Folder");
```

Comment: Thank you sir, that solved my problem! I've always been a bit stuck with IEnumerators etc. Gotta get used to it. It really comes in handy when you know how to work with it.

Comment: There are many coroutine tutorials online. I suggest look at ones about Unity.

Comment: Yeah. At least it's working now (mostly.) Because it's not downloading the full file but like 50/55% of it :P. I'll figure that out I guess

Comment: Ok. If you can't, create a new question and notify me. I will try to run it and see what's happening.

Comment: Will do! I think I'll do it now. Don't have too much time today :/

Comment: Do it anytime you want or have time. I will be notified if you comment.

Comment: I added a question to the site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42455838/unity-file-wwwurl-not-retrieving-all-bytes