# Unity file WWW(url) not retrieving all bytes

Tags: c#, file, unity-game-engine, download, byte

A few moments ago I posted a question because I wasn't able to download a file using WWW() but now I've come to a new problem:

The file that has to be downloaded is ~127mb in size. When I check the file that has been downloaded it shows 55mb. (Which explains why the file isn't able to be opened).

The code I'm using to download the file:

```
IEnumerator WaitForGame(){

    WWW www = new WWW("https://www.dropbox.com/sh/aayo9iud7t98hgb/AACDqSST_-rT2jIfxq1Zc2SXa?dl=1");
    Debug.Log ("Downloading");
    yield return www;
    byte[] yourBytes = www.bytes;

    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(FullPath, yourBytes);
    Debug.Log ("Done downloading!");

}

void UpdateGame(){
    string path = Application.dataPath;
    if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.OSXPlayer) {
        path += "/../../";
    }
    else if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.WindowsPlayer) {
        path += "/../";
    }

    if (System.IO.File.Exists (path+"/Apo_Alpha.app")) {
        Debug.Log ("File exists!");
        System.IO.File.Delete (path+"/Apo_Alpha.app");

    }

    FullPath = path + "/Apo_Alpha.app";


    StartCoroutine (WaitForGame ());












}
```

I have no clue to what the problem can be, and it would be great if someone could help me out with this one.

Comment: hmm try changing the `dl=1` at the end of your dropbox link with `raw=1`. Could be the reason...

Comment: There is no problem with your code. The file you linked is  about 52mb when downloaded from my browser. It's not 127mb as you say.

Comment: Really? I'll check on another pc

Comment: Yeah on Windows for me too. But whenever I check the uploaded version it says 127mb. And if I open the 52mb version it says it's a Power Pc program. So I thought it saw the program as corrupted or something

Comment: I don't know why I wasn't notified about your comments. Use @Programmer next time. The problem is now solved?

Comment: Yeah I have an idea why it's happening. It's because I'm directly converting the .zip file into a .app file. I'll have to unzip it first and then convert it to .app. That should fix the problem